# How to cp all things that DO NOT begins with abc?

Tags: bash

Please don't give me a solution that leverages other commands like grep or ls or sed.

I want to know whether `cp` with a regular expression can do this.

Comment: -iregex. read this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/using-regular-expressions-with-cp or this: http://superuser.com/questions/441422/how-do-you-use-regular-expressions-with-the-cp-command-in-linux or simply google next time before you ask a question

Comment: There's no regular expression in cp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cp(1) itself has no "regular expression" support; the functionality you're depending on is probably Pathname Expansion (globbing) in Bash. Check the bash(1) manpage to find extglob syntax like this:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp !(abc*) destination/
```

Comment: Cool stuff! I didn't remember any of this from when I last read the whole manual. Since when is this in?

Answer (score 3):

```
cp -t elsewhere [^a]* a[^b]* ab[^c]*
```

Note that this:

- doesn't involve regular expressions at all
- involves shell globbing instead, but
- is performed by `bash` not `cp`, and
- is a hand-inversion of `abc*`

Comment: `cp -T` doesn't exist on OSX

Comment: `-T` ====> `-t`  ; `man cp` says `-T` treats DEST as a normal file.  It is `-t` that allows you to specify the destination directory first

Comment: Oops -t/-T confusion.  Thanks Paul, fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you didn't disallow find so here you go:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "abc*" -exec cp '{}' dest/ \;
```